# Hide Pipeline menu from Azure DevOps Dashboard

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to hide the pipeline option from the main azure DevOps dashboard for some specified users.

[image]

Is there any suggestion for me to complete this task? As I have checked all over here and there I couldn't find a document or any link can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only turn off the hubs globally for a whole project.

[image]

There is no way to turn off hubs for specific users.